# I have a python script that generates both letters and numbers combinations of a certain length that can be selected in the settings

Tags: python-3.x, random

I need to make sure that the first character does not change and the others change, help me with this

```
from random import randrange
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, Value
###################################################################
alphabet = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'
cores = cpu_count()
###################################################################
def gen(l):
    return ''.join([alphabet[randrange(0, len(alphabet))] for i in
                    range(l)])
res = open('result.txt', 'a')

def work():
    while True:
            res.write('{0}\n'.format(gen(18)))  
###################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    workers = []
    for r in range(cores):
        p = Process(target=work)
        workers.append(p)
        p.start()
    for worker in workers: worker.join()
    res.close()
###################################################################
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about that but I think this can be easily solved
instead of this

```
def gen(l):
    return ''.join([alphabet[randrange(0, len(alphabet))] for i in range(l)])
```

you can do this (here first char will be M for example)

```
def gen(l):
    return 'M' + ''.join([alphabet[randrange(0, len(alphabet))] for i in range(l-1)])
```

you also can add all chars you want to be your first character in a list and delete any char that is selected before

```
def gen(l):
    chars = ['a','b','c']
    return chars[-1] + ''.join([alphabet[randrange(0, len(alphabet))] for i in range(l-1)])
    chars = chars[:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks to "Mahmoud Noor" everything works super